# pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load("icon.png")) не меняет иконку

Tags: python, icon, pygame

Написал мини игру, пытаюсь сменить иконку, но она не меняется, файл icon.png лежит рядом с py файлом. Прописываю `pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load("icon.png"))` а иконка остается прежней [image: Вот такая иконка]

Comment: попробуйте `"./icon.png"`

Comment: Нет. Все равно не показывается иконка. Иконку пробовал разных размеров, от 32 до 512 никакая не показывается( А еще попробовал полный путь указать, тоже не работает(

Comment: Но когда указываю не существующий файл то выдает ошибку

Comment: А еще заметил что при зависании игры неверно отображается иконка (инверсия)

Answer (score 1):

bmp это родной формат и работает так

```
pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load("icon.bmp"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load("icon.ico"))
```

пробуй переконвертировать в ico, так должно получится

Answer (score 0):

Поменяй разрешение иконки на 16:16

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]